# mysql RDS cpu utilization is 90 % above always for less than for 250 connections ( max conn 1236)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds

I'm using mysql RDS  db.m3.xlarge( 4 vcpus, 15G Ram). max_connection limit is 1236 but cpu is used more than 90% for less than 250 connection. I don't know what I'm struggling to find reason. Please help ?

what should be the ideal value for innodb_thread_concurrency for above configuration?

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here. Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) complete MySQLTuner report E) SHOW  ENGINE INNODB STATUS;  AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, df -h for a linux/unix free space list by device, for server tuning analysis.

Comment: High CPU is almost always an indication of poorly running queries.  EIther look at `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` or the slowlog to find which queries tend to reun the longest, then let's discuss them.  The solution may be to add an index (often 'composite'), and/or to reformulate a query (eg, not hide an indexed column in a function).

Comment: @mahesh If you are using Linux with 4 cores,  90/4 = 22.5% busy.  Posting the requested information will allow us to guide you to improvement of your use of MySQL.